# Localtest.me doesn't work on my machine

Tags: iis, dns, iis-express

I've just tried to do some local testing using the facility explained here:

http://readme.localtest.me

Anything with *.localtest.me will resolve to the local loop back but this isn't working on my machine.

If I ping localtest.me it doesn't resolve.  So my question is am I missing something important here for this to work?

Comment: worked fine on my machine (mac osx) without any extra setup or configuration.

what machine are you running on?

Comment: Windows 7. Does location matter, am in UK? Can you ping it ok?

Comment: yes, when I ping it goes to 127.0.0.1. try using nslookup to see what that address resolves to

Comment: It works ok at work behind a firewall, but not at home using a regular DSL connection. Any ideas?